# Slug adding -2 even though the other posts with the same name is in a separate post type

Tags: permalinks

This is annoying, and because of this I separated their post types.

Now, I have two post types:

1. `motogp-2013`
2. `motogp-2014`

In my post type `motogp-2013` I had an event called 'Grand Prix de France' which turned to 'grand-prix-de-france' as a permalink.

I'm now in the `motogp-2014` post-type and I added a post with the same name 'Grand Prix de France' which turned to 'grand-prix-de-france-2' as a permalink.

Even though they are completely separate post-types, they are adding a 2 after the permalink.

Why is this? Can it be stopped?

Comment: May be a same slugged post is **trashed** in past, and not **deleted permanently**.

Answer (score 0):

If you will take a look to code of [wp_unique_post_slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug) - you will see that...

1. If its post type - **attachment** it will check only `ID` and
   `post_name`
2. If its **hierarchical** post type (page e.g.) - its
   will check for `post_name` on same level (and for sure same
   `post_type`)
3. **nav_menu_item** also `hierarchical` post type but it
   doesn't require any slug so its skipped.
4. Else... it will check for `post_name` if same `post_type`

Please take a look to the 4 item in my list. This is your case.

WP doesn't care if you have such slug in same post_type with a post_status as Draft , Pending or AutoDraft... but let's say if `you have such a post with post_status Published or Trash`... well in this case you obliously (for me) will get `dash + iterator number` in your slug.

if you will run query - may be you will see a different post statuses of the posts of non Uniq slug

```
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `total` ,  `post_name` ,  CONCAT_WS(' and ', post_status) as Statuses
    FROM  `wp_posts` 
    WHERE `post_type` = 'motogp-2013'  
    GROUP BY  CONCAT_WS(' and ', `post_name` ) `post_name` 
    ORDER BY  `total`  DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Still if you not lucky to find out the resone of slug you had want to generate isn't generating... you can use a filter for non uniq slugs...

`wp_unique_post_slug` it can have 7 arguments... ($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ) whish you can use...

```
    add_filter('wp_unique_post_slug', 'se_126293_wp_unique_post_slug',10,7);
    function se_126293_wp_unique_post_slug($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug){
        // do whatever you want with a slug, but whatch out 
        return $slug;
    }
```

You can place this code to your theme's `functions.php` or plugin...

Comment: In your point 2, both my post types are hierarchical. But I don't understand why it is creating a unique slug for posts that are in separate post types? This is what my urls look like... http://moto.com/motogp-2013/grand-prix-de-france, http://moto.com/motogp-2014/grand-prix-de-france-2

Comment: Have you run sql to be sure that yuo don't have same post_name in you post_type?